# Inviting different animals to your camp

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I have reached a limit on the amount of animals that can visit my camp at any given time. Now, whenever I invite someone over, I am informed they can visit any time, however, they end saying, call me when there is room for me to stop by.

**How can I tell certain people to leave to make room for others, and then how do I invite those new people?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are at your campgrounds, tap the animal face on the right side of your screen. This will allow you to kick out and invite new visitors to your grounds.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. >.<